# How to order a list based on what a function returns when called with its items

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

Basically, I need to order a 2D array. Genes is an array of 8 lists, all containing 8  items, all of which are floats. This is for an evolution simulator of sorts, hence 'genes'. My current solution is this:

```
scores = []
[scores.append(score(x)) for x in genes]
unsorted = genes
genes = [unsorted[0]]
for y in range(7):
    for x in range(len(genes)):
        if score(unsorted[y+1]) >= score(genes[x]):
            genes.insert(x, unsorted[y+1])
            break
```

I have a list of all the scores, I save a copy of 'genes' called 'unsorted', and set genes as the first item it once contained. The nested loop underneath should run through unsorted, taking each item through the 'x' loop, and inserting it into 'genes' once it finds the first item of score equal or smaller than its own. I thought this would work, but for some reason, it returns lists of random sizes, like 3, 2 and 5 or even 16. If you have a more efficient or pythonic way to do this, or just one that works, please help!

Comment: Can you show the sample input and expected output ?

Comment: Don't do this: `[scores.append(score(x)) for x in genes]`. List comprehensions are for transforming data, not mutating data. You shouldn't have any side-effects caused by your comprehensions.

Comment: Are you missing some code here? What is `score`? Why are you immediately mutating `genes`?

Comment: "I save a copy of 'genes' called 'unsorted'" - no you don't. `unsorted = genes` doesn't make a copy. Read up on [how Python variables and assignment actually work](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: `scores = [score(x) for x in genes]`... All you're doing in that second line is filling a list with `None` for however many elements are in `genes`.

Comment: @not_a_robot Nah, they are doing something even worse - `.append`ing.

Comment: Word of advice: any modern language will have some built-in sorting function that will be *way more efficient* than what you would probably produce on your own in the language itself. Don't reinvent the wheel. Also, and this is a nitpick, but you aren't working with python arrays, but with python *lists*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what sorted is for.

```
genes =   sorted(genes, key=score)
```

Comment: I don't think he actually needs `unsorted`, so an alternative is `genes.sort(key=score)`.

Comment: This was a VERY rookie question to ask. Should I take it down?

Comment: @Xerxes it wasn't downvoted as a question, it has discussion that was upvoted and an answer that was also upvoted. Even if you could take it down (I'm not sure you can delete once it's been answered), the community has found some value in it. Don't stress :)